# Impact of "Xrender: Jules library not installed" in Java 8 on remote X performance

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java 8 Swing / NetBeans RCP application running on a CentOS 7.6 host that sends the GUI to a remote X display over a 100 Mbps LAN connection. Observation is that the GUI is unexpectedly very slow, and the network load is high even if the GUI does not update a lot. Running the GUI on a local display (same host) instead of via remote X to a remote display is way faster. I am investigating the reason why the GUI reacts so slowly and why the network load for the remote X connection is so high in this constellation.

It is known from earlier versions of similar GUIs that sending a Java Swing GUI via a remote X connection is slow and traffic-intensitive if the Xrender extension is not enabled. Therefore, I am investigating in particular whether the problem may originate here.

The host runs the application with java 8. The Xrender option is explicitly enabled with the -Dsun.java2d.xrender=True option for the java application. Log output reports "XRender pipeline enabled" but also "Xrender: INFO: Jules library not installed."

My questions are:
1. What is the impact of "Jules library not installed" on the performance of sending a GUI over remote X? Will the Xrender extension still be used but will it be slower?
2. Can one expect an improved graphics performance if the Jules library were installed? What exactly needs to be done to install this Jules library on a CentOS 7.6 system to work with java 8?
3. Is there a difference between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK for Java 8 concerning the use of Xrender extension and the Jules library?